# Re-Framing datasets

Tags: r

Hi all I have a got a 2 datasets below. From these 2 datasets(dataset1 is formed from dataset2. I mean the dataset1 is the count of users from dataset2) can we build the the third datasets(expected output)

```
dataset1
Apps  # user Enteries
A        3
B        4
C        6
```

```
dataset2
Apps    Users
A        X
A        Y
A        Z
B        Y
B        Y
B        Z
B        A
C        X
C        X
C        X
C        X
C        X
C        X
```

Expected output

```
Apps    Entries X   Y   Z   A
A          3    1   1   1   
B          4        2   1   1
C          6    6
```

Answer (score 2):

We can first `count` first for `Apps` and `Users`, get the data in wide format and join with the table for `count` of `Apps`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Apps, Users) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Users, values_from = n, 
                     values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  left_join(df %>% count(Apps), by = 'Apps')


#  Apps      X     Y     Z     A     n
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 A         1     1     1     0     3
#2 B         0     2     1     1     4
#3 C         6     0     0     0     6
```

Answer (score 1):

I showing `0` is no problem and having a different column order you can use `table` and `rowSums` to produce the expected output.

```
x <- table(dataset2)
cbind(Entries=rowSums(x), x)
#  Entries A X Y Z
#A       3 0 1 1 1
#B       4 1 0 2 1
#C       6 0 6 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution where you need not have to calculate `Total` separately and do joins...

This solution uses `purrr::pmap` and `dplyr::mutate` for dynamically calculating `Total`.

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr, tidyr, purrr

df %>% count(Apps, Users) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Apps, names_from = Users, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(Total = pmap_int(.l = select_if(., is.numeric),
                          .f = sum))
```

which have output what you need

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Apps      X     Y     Z     A Total
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         1     1     1     0     3
2 B         0     2     1     1     4
3 C         6     0     0     0     6
```